# Method not applicable for arguments regarding generics or type erasure in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I ran into a problem regarding Java generics.

I'm trying to make a listener (called `SomeEventListener`) which listens to `SomeEvent`s to occur. Those events have a result which have a specific type; I want that result to be retrieved through the method `getResult()`, whose return type is `T`. When that event is fired, then the `eventOccurred(SomeEvent<T>)` method is called.

**SomeEvent class:**

```
public class SomeEvent<T> {

    private T result;

    public SomeEvent(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

**SomeEventListener class:**

```
public interface SomeEventListener<T> {

    void eventOccurred(SomeEvent<T> event);

}
```

**AnotherClass class**

```
public class AnotherClass {

    ArrayList<SomeEventListener<?>> listeners = new ArrayList<SomeEventListener<?>>();

    <T> void fireSomethingOccursEvent(SomeEvent<T> event) {
        for (SomeEventListener<?> listener : this.listeners) {
            listener.eventOccurred(event); // MARKED LINE
        }
    }
}
```

But hey, Eclipse gives an error on the MARKED LINE:

> The method eventOccurred(SomeEvent<capture#2-of ?>) in the type SomeEventListener<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (SomeEvent<T>)

I have suspects why this occurs – it possibly has something to do with generics and type erasure – but I cannot solve it.

My questions:

- Why is the abovementioned code invalid?
- How can I fix the code?

*Notice: Posts about generics and/or type erasure are plenty; however, I couldn't find the answer to this question. If you think another answer is suitable, please link to it.*

Comment: If you search for type safe generic heterogenous container you might get something related to your issue. Don't have much time to investigate the issue, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `SomeEventListener<?>`, with a method `void eventOccurred(SomeEvent<?> event)` (substituting `?` as `T`).

You also have a `SomeEvent<T>` for some completely unrelated `T`.

You can't convert this to a `SomeEvent<?>` - in fact, you can't convert anything to a `SomeEvent<?>` except for `null`. `?` means "I have no idea what this type argument is."

As an example, if your code was allowed, this code would compile, but pass the wrong type:

```
AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();

ac.listeners.add(new SomeEventListener<Integer>() {
    void eventOccurred(SomeEvent<Integer> event) {
        System.out.println(event.intValue());
    }
});

SomeEvent<String> event = new SomeEvent<String>("Hello");
ac.fireSomethingOccursEvent(event);
```

Now `fireSomethingOccursEvent` would take the `SomeEvent<String>` and pass it to a `SomeEventListener<Integer>`. This obviously should not be allowed - so, it's not allowed.

Comment: A little late, but I have accepted your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make whole `AnotherClass` generic and use [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
public class AnotherClass<T> {

    ArrayList<SomeEventListener<? super T>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    //use diamond-type since java 1.7

    void fireSomethingOccursEvent(SomeEvent<? extends T> event) {
        for (SomeEventListener<? super T> listener : this.listeners) {
            listener.eventOccurred(event); // should be fine
        }
    }
}
```